# Remove filler spaces from blank lines in linux script

Tags: macos

I am trying to work on a bash script that will take files from one github repo and copy them over to another one.

I have this mostly working however 1 file I am trying to move over has spaces on all of its blank lines like so:

```
FROM metrics_flags ORDER BY DeliveryDate ASC
)
                        
SELECT * FROM selected;
""";
```

Notice how its not just a blank line, there are actually 10-20 spaces in between the 2 blocks of code on that blank line.
Is there some unix command that can parse the file and remove the spaces (but keep the blank line)?

I tried

```
awk 'NF { $1=$1; print }' file.txt
```

and

```
sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//' file.txt
```

with no success.

Comment: A straightforward `sed 's/^[[:blank:]]*$//'` should do the trick. Not all `sed`s support `\t` as a tab character.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` used without changing delimeters splits `records` (lines) into white-space-separated `fields`. By default any print commands obey the same separators for the output but any empty fields can be removed resulting in their white-space-separators not being used.

The 'trick' is to get `awk` to re-evaluate the line by setting any field (even empty ones) to itself:

```
awk '{$1=$1; print}' test.txt
```

will remove all white space that is not surrounding other printable characters and return the file contents to stdout where it can be redirected to file if required.

I don't know why you used `NF` as a `pattern` in your `awk` attempt, nor why it caused it to fail, but the similar approach without it, as above, works fine.

**edit** after a quick experiment, I think what was happening with your `awk` attempt was that setting the `pattern` to `NF` caused `awk` to skip lines with no printable fields completely. Removing that `pattern` allows the now empty lines to be printed.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you describe, replacing leading whitespace only from empty lines:

`sed -E 's|^\s+$||' file`

The -E (extended regex) is required for \s+ (\t also), meaning one or more whitespace characters. I think you might have accidentally used a lower e.

If you like the output, you can add -i to apply the edit to your file.

This is an example of using awk to achieve the same:

`awk '{gsub(/^\s+$/, "")}; { print }' file`

To apply it, use `-i inplace`:

`awk -i inplace '{gsub(/^\s+$/, "")}; { print }' file`

I tested this on Ubuntu 22.04 with GNU sed 4.8 and GNU awk 5.1.0

Answer (score -2):

Odd ...

```
sed -i 's/^[[:space:]]*$//g' file.txt
```

definitely works for me; I don't see why your `sed` version wouldn't, though.

On MacOS, this works (**TESTED**):

```
sed -E -i ""  's/^[[:space:]]*$//g' file.txt
```

Comment: Im on OSX, and this command wont run successfully. Tried it with a -e instead of a -i and it ran but didn't do anything

Comment: Maybe if you gave people correct information (OS, for instance) you'd get correct answers :P. @BradySnelson ... I've edited my answer with a MacOS version.